# Is it possible to set a Custom quick look preview image in OS X?

Tags: applescript, command-line, quicklook

Is there any way to set a custom quick look image in OS X? I'd like a command line tool or applescript to change or embed a custom preview for a file using a jpeg.

Comment: Have you taken a look on http://www.quicklookplugins.com/ ? There might already be quicklook plugin for your filetype...

Comment: I'm dealing with a digital camera RAW file. The preview is created by the camera and doesn't reflect any changes I've made in my RAW converter.

Answer (score 1):

No. The way Quick Look works is that a plugin, which recognizes your file, is required. Only such plugins can supply images to QL.